# Loading the native library in runtime is taking more time when encrypted with dexguard

Tags: android, proguard, dexguard, android-native-library

I have integrated dexguard in my android application. Everything is working fine.

I have also encrypted the native libraries using dexguard. The problem here is when I apply dexguard it takes few seconds to load the native library whereas without dexguard it loads immediately. If I remove `-encryptnativelibraries` from the dexguard properties file, then it loads immediately.

I guess decrytping the .so file in run-time is taking few seconds? Or should it not take this long?

Comment: if you are doing something `extra` than obviously it will take more time than usual. bdw *what is your issue now?* be clear on stackoverflow. please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: System.loadLibrary("sample") loads so file. This doesnot usually take time. But When I encrypt so file with dexguard and load the library it is taking around 10seconds. So I had to take extra care of putting progress bar. My question here is that this time delay is an expected one??? Or Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you testing on `Device` or `Emulator` ?

Comment: 10 seconds is too long then

Comment: What should I do about it?

Comment: make a async task and load the lib in background.

Comment: @PavaniReddy Hi, Now I am also facing that issue. How can we solve the issue ? Did you get solution for that ?

Comment: @KarthickRamu No I dont have solution for this problem. Dexguard needs to decrypt the encrypted libraries when they are loaded. So it will indeed take some time.

Comment: A lot is going to depend on the hardware and how much support for encryption it has. Hardware decryption can be 1000 times slower in software than in top-of-the-line hardware encryption on a phone. Keep in mind users that have older/cheaper phones.

Answer (score 2):

Old versions of DexGuard did the loading of encrypted native libraries in a quite inefficient way. More recent versions 7.1.20+ improved the performance of the decryption and loading and you should not notice much difference anymore compared to an unencrypted library.